# How can I prevent v-navigation-drawer from shortening texts inside on Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, frameworks, frontend, vuetify.js

I've been looking for a way to prevent v-navigation-drawer from shortening texts by itself on Vuetify. When I fill some spaces with text in the v-navigation-drawer, the text goes like "gobbled...". I mean, I want the tags inside to smoothly text such as "gobbledygook". How can I achieve this? I hope the image below helps you what's the problem exactly is.

Problem: I don't want v-navigation-drawer to shorten the texts inside of itself. 
[image]


Edit: The code goes like:

```
<v-navigation-drawer 
 dark 
 color="#fff" 
 width="160" 
 v-model="is_drawer" 
 v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown">
 // many <v-list-item> and <v-list-group> inside here
 // and shrinking-text problem occurs on v-list-item-title
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Comment: please share the code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim here it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the list title item title, to fix this add the following CSS rules  :

```
.v-list-item__subtitle, .v-list-item__title{
      text-overflow: initial!important;
    white-space: initial!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The list item text is automatically truncated when the length of text is too long. Although there is no built-in method to disable text truncation, it can be disabled by using the class `d-flex` on `v-list-item-title`, since text truncation requires display block.

To allow long text to wrap, there is another helper class `text-wrap`.

See this codesandbox with all options in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-voice-bbxtg?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue